# Mount K8s PVC to hidden container directory

Tags: kubernetes, storage, guacamole, kubernetes-pvc

I am struggeling to mount a PVC to /root/.guacamole in my pod. Mounting to /root/extensions works, but .guacamole doesn't let the pod boot. Basically, I would like to include the file guacamole-auth-totp-1.1.0.jar to the existing containers location /root/.guacamole/extensions (dont replace; even though kubernetes does not support that too well):

**Works**

```
        volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/root/extensions"
        name: vol-guacamole
        subPath: guacamole-auth-totp-1.1.0.jar
  volumes:
    - name: vol-guacamole
      persistentVolumeClaim: 
        claimName: guacamole-app-pvc
```

**Fails**

```
        volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/root/.guacamole/extensions"
        name: vol-guacamole
        subPath: guacamole-auth-totp-1.1.0.jar
  volumes:
    - name: vol-guacamole
      persistentVolumeClaim: 
        claimName: guacamole-app-pvc
```

[Kubectl get all -o wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knt85.png)

[kubectl describe pod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1RyV.png)

```
kubectl logs pod
rm: cannot remove '/root/.guacamole/extensions': Device or resource busy
```

**Kubernetes Version**

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:20:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0", GitCommit:"70132b0f130acc0bed193d9ba59dd186f0e634cf", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-12-07T21:12:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**PV and PVC (without file mount)**

```
kubectl get pv,pvc -n guacamole
NAME                                             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                      STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
[...]
persistentvolume/guacamole-app-pv                10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    guacamole/guacamole-app-pvc                manual                  4d15h
[...]

NAME                                      STATUS   VOLUME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/guacamole-app-pvc   Bound    guacamole-app-pv   10Gi       RWO            manual         4d15h
```

**PV and PVC (with file mount)**

```
kubectl get pv,pvc -n guacamole
NAME                                             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                      STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
[...]
persistentvolume/guacamole-app-pv                10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    guacamole/guacamole-app-pvc                manual                  39s
[...]

NAME                                      STATUS   VOLUME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/guacamole-app-pvc   Bound    guacamole-app-pv   10Gi       RWO            manual         39s
```

Comment: What is your k8s version? Can you post the PV and PVC that you are using?

Comment: I updated the question. Thanks for supporting!

Comment: I will try a different approach by updating the docker image before deployment for making my changes. This way I won't have to face the incompatibility between docker and kubernetes.

Comment: Kind of getting lost now. What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Pod fails to start, having error: kubectl logs pod
rm: cannot remove '/root/.guacamole/extensions': Device or resource busy

Comment: One more question, does the access rights are exactly the same for `.guacamole/extensions` and `/extensions`?

Comment: Access rights are the same for both locations.